# How to verify Jmeter Recorded Load Test Results

Tags: graph, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have created a recorded test plan for my web application using Jmeter. My web application basically creates a financial plan for new and existing customers. I recorded all the steps required to create a financial plan for a new customer. 
I am not sure how to validate if Jmeter actually runs recorded steps. I am using Graph Results and checking throughput at the end of the recorded plan.

I am not sure how to validate if Jmeter is actually running all Thread users with the recorded steps. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should check for the effects of the script in your application. For example if you're creating a new plan, once you run the script, there should be a new plan in the application. A jmeter treeview listener shows you the request and responses for each sampler in your script.

Comment: thanks i checked the last updated timestamp of my plan and it has not changed.. not sure why its not working

Comment: The answer almost always is some dynamic value like jsessionID or cookies. Results Tree should help you debug which page is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your test plan and execute your test with 1-2 virtual users. Inspect "Response Data" tab of each request to ensure it does what it is supposed to do

[image: View Results Tree]

If you use any JMeter Variables and want to check their values - add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)(s) to Test Plan where needed. Variables values can be checked via aforementioned View Results Tree listener.

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for advanced information on debugging your JMeter test.

Don't forget to remove or disable View Results Tree listener for the actual load test as it is too resource intensive. Also make sure you run JMeter in [command-line non-GUI](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) mode for the actual load.

Comment: so i checked  Tree Results and found Handshake Issue - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure.. checked some posts and could not find anything helpful. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: It looks like you need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate - `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` to your browser. See [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) for detailed instructions

Comment: import is not a probelm, i think the problem was proxy server. I changed the proxy port to 443 and it worked. Now i am getting 403 Forbidden while accessing my web application.